# Entity Class object cannot be updated

Tags: entities

I'm using the [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) in my module and I'm starting to feel headache with so many problems.

If you think this is a duplicate of [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21023) or [this other](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69728) you are wrong, just keep reading

I need an Entity to represent a work centre of an organization, this is the simplest case possible since I only need one field, the centre’s name (and obviously on the database table I will need an ID).

Well, I already passed trough the problems described on the questions linked in the previous paragraph, but it was not enough.

I specified the `setter callback` for the centre's name, I even specified the `schema field` on which relies the property. I used my own setter and with the `dpm()` function provided by the Devel module I discovered that the object's instance seems immutable, I tried to update the value but didn't worked, probably I could get rid of the entity class and use the metadata wrapper for updating the values, but that could have side effects.

Comment: please show us your entity declarations, such as `hook_entity_info` and any other Entity APIs you've implemented.

Comment: @tenken Oh! I forgot to copy the code from the job's laptop, I will update this question with the code tomorrow. However on the `setter callback` I printed the object before modify the value and after and the `dpm()` shown that the value didn't change at all.

Comment: @tenken Forget about the code I already solved it, the funny thing is that the problem was not on the Entity API, but on the form. Nobody told me that using `#value` on a Textfield will cause ignore the user input, I changed that for `#default_value`