# How to use external JSON API to create/update node's fields?

Tags: 7, feeds

I have a content type: `siteinfo`.

This content type has multiple fields: text, entity reference etc.

**I want to use an external API to automatically fill some fields of the created node.**

The API I want to use says that:

> API returns consistent and well-structured data in XML & JSON
>   format. Returned data contains parsed fields that can easily be
>   used by your application. This is a RESTful based API.

And this is the API's output:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "api_query": "siteinfo",
    "whois_record": {
        "domain_name": "example.com",
        "query_time": "2016-05-05 14:01:12",
        "create_date": "1995-08-14",
        "update_date": "2015-08-14",
        "expiry_date": "2016-08-13",
        "domain_registrar": {
            "iana_id": 376,
            "registrar_name": "RESERVED-INTERNET ASSIGNED NUMBERS AUTHORITY",
            "whois_server": "whois.iana.org",
            "referral_url": "http://res-dom.iana.org"
        },
        "name_servers": [
            "a.iana-servers.net",
            "b.iana-servers.net"
        ],
    },
}
```

[image]

### How can I use this external API?

Answer (score 2):

If there's no complicated authentication/request method for the service (e.g. a simple HTTP GET for http://service.example.com/api/siteinfo/1), then a combination of [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds), [Feeds extensible parsers](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ex), & [Libraries](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) with the [JMESPath library](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.php) installed works great here.

The Feeds module has an HTTP fetcher that can be used in conjunction with the **JSON JMESPath parser** that allows you to enter [JMESPath queries](http://jmespath.org/) for each field you want parse and insert/update into a node (e.g. in the parser settings you'd could put "@" (root) as the **Context** & "whois_record. domain_name" if you wanted to map that object's property to a node field).

In this solution, Feeds is handling the import/update bookkeeping while you're tasked with figuring out the correct queries to parse the data. If you go this path, it's very helpful to [study JMESPath syntax](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html) while using the [Feeds Import Preview](https://www.drupal.org/project/feedspreview) module to test your imports before execution.

If you need your URL to vary for each import, you can [wrap a programmatic invocation of a Feeds import](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90062/programmatically-execute-feed-import) into a function and call it for each imported URL in a `drush eval` or some other arbitrary location in your environment. For example:

```
//$url = Is your imported feed.
//$my_feed = Your imported feed machine name 
//(i.e. the MY_FEED_MACHINE_NAME in http://example.com/import/MY_FEED_MACHINE_NAME)
function MYMODULE_import_feed($url, $my_feed) {
  $feeds_source = feeds_source($my_feed);
  $feeds_config = $feeds_source->getConfigFor($feeds_source->importer->fetcher);
  $feeds_config['source'] = $url;
  $feeds_source->setConfigFor($feeds_source->importer->fetcher, $feeds_config);
  $feeds_source->save();
  $feeds_source->startImport();
}

//Example execution 
function MYMODULE_cron() {
  $import_titles = array('title_1', 'title_2');
  foreach ($import_titles as $title) {
    MYMODULE_import_feed("http://service.example.com/api/siteinfo/$title",'MY_FEED_MACHINE_NAME');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Actually, I'm already using the **Simple** method (Feeds + Feeds Ex) but there were some problems for me: For each node I had to create a different Feed importer but I don't want to do this. What I want to do is to create a **generic** Feed importer such as `http://service.example.com/api/siteinfo/[NODE:TITLE]` and every time I create a node then the Feeds importer works automatically and the node's fields filled with the external data. **Is this possible?** // Sorry if I mis-explained the situation in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @herci `create a generic Feed importer such as http://service.example.com/api/siteinfo/[NODE:TITLE]`I am afraid it is not possible, but you can make it possible by building a custom module and using [hook_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x) Also, see [Updating a field programmatically, hook_node_update](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21023/updating-a-field-programmatically-hook-node-update) to auto fill out the feed url field. PS: Make sure you're usin [attach to content type](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uguQo.jpg)

Comment: @herci, I've updated the solution to your particular scenario while addressing generic URL importing.

Answer (score 1):

#### The no coding, clean hands, solution:

Feeds + [Feeds JSONPath Parser](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_jsonpath_parser)

#### Coding, dirty hands, solution:

Using REST with [Webservices](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) you can Get and then Post/Patch. You would also need to comeup with a way to schedule your code so it runs every x amount of time (create a cron job); in contrast, Feeds already has that feature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm already using the "new" version of the Feeds JSONPath Parser. Please see my comment on other answer: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200217/how-to-use-external-json-api-to-create-update-nodes-fields#comment242276_200393